# Disposable that depends on other Disposables

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that processes file streams based on a list of strings, and the string can either be a file on disk, or a file inside a Zip file.  To clean up the code, I'd like to refactor out the process of opening the file.

I've created a method that returns a Stream of the file contents, but because the stream depends on the ZipFile IDisposable, by the time I read the stream, the ZipFile is disposed an throws an exception.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = OpenFileForImport("zipfile.zip;insidefile.txt"))
        new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd(); // Exception

    using (var stream = OpenFileForImport("outside.txt"))
        new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd(); // Works
}
public static Stream OpenFileForImport(string filePath)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(basefolder, filePath);

    if (path.Contains(";"))
    {
        var parts = path.Split(';');
        var zipPath = parts[0];

        //Error checking logic to ensure zip file exists and is valid...
        using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        using (var entry = zip.GetEntry(parts[1]))
        {
            //Error checking logic to ensure inside file exists within zip file.
            return entry.Open();
        }

    }

    var file = new FileInfo(path);
    if (file != null)
        return file.OpenRead();

    return null;

}
```

I could remove the using clause from the `zip` and `entry` declarations, but I doubt they'd ever get disposed.  Is there an appropriate pattern to return a disposable, when it depends on other disposables?

Comment: You could return a custom `Stream` implementation that owns the disposables and disposes them in its own `Dispose` method.

Comment: You need to use encapsulation and implement your own class that uses the disposal interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return the stream directly, instead return a disposable object which can provide the stream you want to dispose, but that cleans up that stream *and the other dependant resources* when it is disposed of:

```
public class NameToBeDetermined : IDisposable
{
    private ZipFile zip;
    public Stream Stream { get; }
    public NameToBeDetermined(ZipFile zip, Stream stream)
    {
        this.zip = zip;
        Stream = stream;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        zip.Dispose();
        Stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then return *that*, rather than the stream itself.  If it's worth spending the time, you could turn that wrapper into a `Stream` itself, that just forwards all `Stream` methods into the composed stream, but that does the extra work when disposing.  Whether it's worth the time to create that more involved wrapper rather than having a caller access a `Stream` property is up to you.

Comment: This was the solution I ended up going with... What did you mean by "that does the extra work when disposing."  If I dispose all my contained objects, am I risking anything by having the wrapper in place?

Comment: @MattMurrell The "extra work when disposing" is disposing of other dependent objects.  What are you worried about by having a wrapper, what problem are you thinking it's going to cause?

Answer (score 1):

You likely should copy the file from the `ZipEntry` into a `MemoryStream` so that you have a copy to work with.

```
    //Error checking logic to ensure zip file exists and is valid...
    using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    using (var entry = zip.GetEntry(parts[1]))
    {
        //Error checking logic to ensure inside file exists within zip file.
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        entry.Open().CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: That's assuming that the file even fits into memory.  A method accessing an arbitrary file in an arbitrary zip almost certainly can't make such an assumption.

Comment: @Servy that's true, but i'm guessing with the calls to `ReadToEnd` it should.

Comment: That's one example call, not necessarily representative of every single call (otherwise the method itself would read the whole thing and return *that*, rather than a stream, which is what you should do if you actually want it to pull the whole file into memory).

Comment: As a general rule, if returning a Stream, I would return it at Position 0.